# Why is this program not giving the expected output

Tags: python-3.x

MY CODE :

```
n = int(input())
arr = []

for i in range(0,n):
    s = input().split()

    for i in range(1,len(s)) :
        s[i] = int(s[i])
        if s[0] == "append" :
            arr.append(s[1])
        elif s[0] == "insert" :
            arr.insert(s[1],s[2])  
        elif s[0] == "print" :
            print(arr)            
        elif s[0] == "reverse" :
            arr.reverse()               
        elif s[0] == "sort" :
            arr.sort()               
        elif s[0] == "pop" :
            arr.pop()               
        elif s[0] == "remove" :
            arr.remove(s[1])
```

INPUT :

12

insert 0 5

insert 1 10

insert 0 6

print

remove 6

append 9

append 1

sort

print

pop

reverse

print

EXPECTED OUTPUT :

[6, 5, 10]

[1, 5, 9, 10]

[9, 5, 1]

MY OUTPUT :

(No Output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your lines from `if s[0] == "append"` to the end of the code are indented one level too many, making them part of the loop that converts the parameters to ints.  This loop executes zero times for commands with no parameters, so in particular the "print" command does nothing.

Comment: Thank you so much !